# Directional derivative in direction of motion

Tags: functions, derivatives, dynamical-systems

If we have a function, $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+x^2+3y^2}$. How can we find the directional derivative in the direction of motion if $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=t(t-2)$ for $t>0$.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should try it on your own first before asking!

Comment: @James Lucas: We're happy to help, but we can best help you if we know why this problem is tricky for you.  For example: do you know the definition of "directional derivative" (if so, what is it)?  Have you seen solved problems involving directional derivatives before (perhaps because you solved them)?  Are you stuck on some algebraic manipulation?  Etc.  (I think this is also what weilam06 means by their comment.)

Comment: Yes I have given it a go myself. Having replaced x and y with t and t(t-2) respectively, I wasn’t sure how to then calculate the directional derivative since f is not a function of only one variable. Also, I’m not sure on what direction the direction of motion is, since I’ve tried it to be the derivative of f but ended up with 0 as my final answer.